# MVC Requesting File Download - how to handle no file available?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm relatively new to MVC but suppose I have a `@Html.ActionLink(....` on my page that links to an Action that generates a file and returns it using:

```
return File(memoryStream, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

This all works well until there's some kind of issue - either something's gone wrong or there's no file to return.

Returning `null` makes the webpage go to a blank page. So my question is... How can I gracefully handle this scenario? - ideally displaying some error to the user that something went wrong or there's no file/data available or if this isn't possible, then just ensuring the page doesn't go to a blank page, and just remains as it is.

I suppose I could redirect to the index action but this will refresh the page - are there any alternatives.

Comment: I assume you are working with a file result....you need to add a condition just like in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434345/redirecting-to-mvc-actionresult-from-fileresult

Comment: Can you render the actionlink only if the file exists? `File.Exists(pathToFile)`

Comment: @NicholasV. unfortunately no as the file is generated from the database, I would have do do all the "file processing" on the page load.

Comment: @Hackerman - exactly the same situation but the answer is what I'm trying to avoid - reloading the page or another page.

Answer (score 1):

I would do one of two things:

1. Return a `404 Not Found` response:

   ```
   return HttpNotFound();
   ```
2. Render a "friendly" error page:

   ```
   try
   {
       if (File.Exists(...))
       {
           // Download file
       }
       else
       {
           return View("FileNotFound");
       }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       return View("FileError", ex);
   }
   ```